# How to evaluate joint importance of two features in a model (random forest) using R package such as VIP or DALEXtra?

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection, tidymodels

I know to use these packages (VIP etc) with tidymodels to evaluate individual feature contribution/importance for a model such as random forest. But I'd like to know to evaluate a combined or joint importance for two or more features? Probably I cannot just simply add importance scores of these features together?

Thank you.

-Xiaokuan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`variable_groups`](https://ema.drwhy.ai/featureImportance.html#featureImportanceR) argument in `DALEX::model_parts` function.

Comment: Yes. that's correct. Is there a way to use VIP package to do that?